# Pool takes up all memory and crashes when loading a large text file

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

Originally I had a program that processes a large text file, but pool would use up all my memory and I would eventually crash. I tried to narrow down the problem by removing parts of my program until I reached this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


import pickle
with open('d.data', 'rb') as handle:
    text = pickle.load(handle)

def preprocess(d):
    print(d)
    return d
# del text
d = ['hay','hay','hay','hay','hay','hay','hay','hay']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('pool initiated')
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            pool.map(preprocess, d)
```

As you can see, pool does not use the large text file loaded with pickle but still uses up all memory and takes a very long time to run. If I remove the code that loads the file, it runs fine and finishes in a split second. Loading the file by itself only takes around 70% of memory. I also tried deleting the text file before I ran pool but that didn't do anything. I'm guessing the problem has something to do with memory but I have no idea why, and how to fix it.

Comment: I see you have: `if __name__ == '__main__':`. This is the right thing to do. Why is this the right thing to do?

Comment: If you're not on Linux and using the fork start method for multiprocessing, each subprocess will also load your data to memory separately.